# Am I impdp dump file in Oracle database 11g R2, right?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I have a dump file without log file,I have no idea what the expdp schema users are,so editing a parfile like below:

```
    directory=my directory 
    remap_schema=rx:tbs
    table_exist_action=replace
```

My problem is that the user "rx" is not exist,IMPDP by the way above, Whether or not IMPDP load all objects properly to database

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need a log file
- it is unclear whether you got that parameter file, or did you write it yourself

  - I *think* the former; otherwise, how would you know about the `rx` user?

    - if that's so, you shouldn't worry about the `rx` user - it looks as if dumpfile contains objects that belong(ed) to that user
    - what you should have is the `tbs` user (created in the target database). Why? Because of the `remap_schema` parameter. Certainly, you don't have to import into `tbs`; create any other user and fix the parameter file
- that's it, then; import the dumpfile as e.g.

  ```
  impdp system/password@database parfile=that_parameter_file.txt
  ```

Comment: thanks  Littlefoot for your help, the parameter file I know how to write it correctly,  The problem is that  I only have dump file, I don't  get the right expdp schema users or expdp log, so I try to give a false user "rx" (original database doesn't have that user) , I want to ask whether impdp load it correctly by this way.